# Map Programing in C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary

I Want to write a Windows Application that uses an  map and when a user clicks on a location in the map,the application shows some information about the location which are saved in a  a database file.

how can i write codes for map?
what component can i use?
what library can i use?
any information can help me ...

Comment: What have you looked at and read and tried?

Comment: @mohsen You really need to appreciate people trying to help by marking as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in map control in C#. You'll have to use some third party library. For a straight up map, I would suggest OpenStreetMaps, Bing Maps or Google Maps. There is a pretty good blog post with how to develop a C# maps API [here](http://linqtotwitter.wordpress.com/2005/10/05/google-maps-api-in-c/). There's also a pretty good Bing Maps / vs Google Maps comparison [here](http://sandersn.com/blog//index.php/2010/03/07/bing-maps-api).

If you want a full fledged Earth viewer, you have basically 3 main choices:

- Nasa World Wind
- Microsoft (Bing) Virtual Earth
- Google Earth

Nasa World Wind has a Java SDK and off the top of my head -- I don't know of any C# SDKs for Nasa World Wind. From a user experience perspective, I don't think Nasa World Wind is as good as Bing or Google Earth.

I don't have a lot of experience with Bing virtual earth either, there are quite a few references:

- [Developing a .NET Application Using Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx)
- [Bing Maps SDK](http://connect.microsoft.com/bingmapapps)

Most of my mapping expertise comes from Google Earth, which does not have a native C# API. The older versions (< GE 6) had a COM API, and the web version has a JavaScript API, but there is nothing native for C#. However, there is an *excellent* 3rd party C# library [here](http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/). Note that that library uses the Google Earth plugin that runs in a web browser control. Fortunately it uses late binding (.NET 4.0), so it should be compatible with any version of the plugin.

Good luck!

Comment: There are already some opensource controls that can be found on codeplex.com.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at
http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/
It is a great solution we use for gis

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this control?

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/